# I can't login for first time in Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, system-installation, 18.04

I installed several times, test with several passwords, and I can't login for the first time, so my server is inaccessible.

I read that a lot of people have the same problem, some of them solved restarting, changing keyboard, but none of those solutions work for me.

Any idea of how to solve this problem?

Comment: At the login prompt, you put in your username and then you are asked for your password and you enter it and what, then, is the response?

Comment: the response is incorrect password